# Facebook Graph API - delete like

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm developing an app for Facebook in PHP, part of which lists the user's "likes". I would like to add a link next to each like so that the user can manage their likes by deleting them where they see fit.

Facebook mentions this in their graph api docs:

> You can delete a like by issuing a DELETE request to /POST_ID/likes (since likes don't have an ID).

But each like must have an id - how else would you delete it?

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, likes don't have an ID in the Graph API.  You like or unlike an item by POSTing or DELETEing to `{item_id}/likes`, where `{item_id}` is replaced by the ID of the object you're liking/unliking.

To find out what the current user has liked (so you can delete them appropriately), you can use the "likes" connection of the User object ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)).  So, if you request `http://graph.facebook.com/me/likes`, you'll get a list of pages/people/whatever that a user has liked.  (Note: this does not include posts or photos or things like that)

This will return an array of data full of items like this:

```
{
     "name": "Very Hungry Caterpillar",
     "category": "Artist",
     "id": "29956247793",
     "created_time": "2009-03-27T15:48:29+0000"
}
```

The ID in there is ***not*** the ID of the like.  It is the ID of the object that the user has liked, so in order to un-like it, you have to make a DELETE to `http://graph.facebook.com/29956247793/likes`.

Comment: I just tried to do this via Facebook's graph API explorer and it didn't work for me.  It gave the error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
Is this method still working for you?

Comment: @Mike - which permissions did you request for your app?  Your error sounds like you might be missing a permission.  (And yes, it worked for me two years ago when I wrote this answer, but I haven't tested it since)

Comment: I granted all permissions possible when I tried it but paid special attention to publish_actions.  No luck.  Either I'm doing something wrong or the graph API explorer has limited functionality or Facebook no longer supports this.

Comment: I've the same error  { "error": { "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 3 } }.   It's possible to delete likes by API ?

Answer (score 5):

It's not the 'like' that has an ID, it's the post - which is why the api call uses '/POST_ID/likes' as a target - if you delete '/POST_ID', it'll get rid of the post, but if you delete '/POST_ID/likes' it'll get rid of the user's 'like' for that post.

Comment: Facebook documents it, but doesn't implement it ... `Method Not Implemented`

Answer (score 1):

Likes do have an ID.

If you look at https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes, you will see that the resulting data does contain an ID value for each.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Audi",
         "category": "Consumer_products",
         "id": "96585976469",
         "created_time": "2010-09-27T15:30:15+0000"
      }
    ]
}
```

You might want to try the ID's there, I've noticed that the FB API doc sometimes has errors.

**Edit**: I think this also may be a terminology issue, as what the doc says doesn't have ID's is probably likes to a user post, and these probably don't really have an ID and can be removed by issuing a delete to the POST_ID/likes. Then there's the likes generated by liking pages and/or external websites via the like-button, and these DO have an ID. Confusing, it is.

Comment: Thanks TuomasR, I can get the likes as you specify using $likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes'); which returns an object similar to that you have displayed above. I'm wondering what url or fb javascript method would be used to remove a specific like? Maybe the best way to do this is to reverse engineer the like and get the url of the like like so: $likeParams = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$like['id'])); $likeParams->{$like['id']}->link; and then add a like button for each. Here you could choose to unlike the item.

Comment: That's not an ID for the "like", that's the ID of the object being "liked".  So, to unlike that object, you would have to make a DELETE to `https://graph.facebook.com/96585976469/likes".

Answer (score 1):

You *unlike* using `access_token` which used to make this *like*.

Pseudocode:

#### to like:

```
FacebookGraphApi::getInstance()->setAccessToken('xxx')->post('xxxxxx/likes')
```

#### to unlike:

```
FacebookGraphApi::getInstance()->setAccessToken('xxx')->delete('xxxxx/likes')
```

Answer (score 1):

With OpenGrpah, likes do have ids, it is the single id field in the object returned by an API call to og.likes.