# How to do unlike the wall post which is like by the user in facebook using the graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to do unlike the wall post which is like by the user in facebook..
and I am using the graph API in android for mobile Application...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) how to ask a proper question here. *"I want to do X"* is neither a question nor a suitable statement for StackOverflow. Show things you found out while doing your research and an attempt to solve this problem on your own (even if it doesn't work). Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook graph api - delete like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832405/facebook-graph-api-delete-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple and worked for me in past. Fire a **id_of_comment_you_already_liked/unlike** request.